# Pyplot / matplotlib line plot - same color

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I plot a simple line plot with matplotlib/pyplot. In the same plot, there are up to 20 lines. Matplotlib automatically chooses a line color. 
I need to draw the first of the lines in a thicker red.

So i tried:

```
if (i==0):                       # first line
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r', lw=2.5)
else:                            # other lines
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

So far very simple. First line is correct. But one of the other lines is red too. How can avoid this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The default `jet` color map goes from blue to red. Every builtin colormap also has a sister color map with the colors going in reverse order. The reversed color map has the same name with the suffix `_r`. Thus, `jet_r` goes from red to blue.

So you can give each line a unique color from the `jet_r` colormap by defining

```
color = cmap(float(i)/N)
```

where `cmap` is the `jet_r` colormap. 
The colormap `cmap` is a callable. When passed a float, it returns a RGB tuple.
Thus, if `float(i)/N` is a distinct float between 0 and 1 for each line, then each line will automatically get a distinct color.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 100)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('jet_r')
N = 20
for i, n in enumerate(np.linspace(2.0, 0, N)):
    y = np.sin(x)*x**n
    color = cmap(float(i)/N)
    lw = 2.5 if i==0 else 1
    # zorder controls the order in which the lines are drawn. 
    # The line with the highest zorder lies on top.
    plt.plot(x, y, c=color, lw=lw, zorder=-i)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Comment: One up for that eye pleasing plot

Comment: What is N in this line? `color = cmap(float(i)/N)`

Comment: `N` is the number of lines. It's 20 in the plot above.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways you could potentially do this. Probably the simplest and most obvious would be to specify separate line colors for all 20 lines:

```
line_colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', ...]

for ii in range(20):
    plt.plot(x, y, c=line_colors[ii])
```

Of course it would a bit of a pain to have to type out 20 different color strings!

You could also generate the colors by drawing an array of RGBA values from a colormap as in unutbu's answer, but most of the built-in colormaps contain red, so you'd have to either pick a colormap that doesn't contain red, [design your own](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html), or pick a range of float values between 0 and 1 that did not map to the red region of the colormap.

If you don't mind some colors being repeated, one potentially nicer option would be to use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to create a generator object that yields colors in a repeating cycle:

```
from itertools import cycle

color_cycle = cycle(['g', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k'])

for ii in range(20):
    if ii == 0:
        plt.plot(x, y, c='r')
    else:
        plt.plot(x, y, c=cycle.next())
```

In fact, this is exactly how the default matplotlib color cycle works. Each axis object contains an `itertools.cycle` which sequentially changes the default color for each line that is drawn on that axis:

```
ax = plt.axes()

ax_color_cycle = ax._get_lines.color_cycle

print(ax_color_cycle)
# <itertools.cycle object at 0x7fdb91efae60>

print(ax_color_cycle.next())
# b

print(ax_color_cycle.next())
# g

print(ax_color_cycle.next())
# r

# etc.
```

Comment: So maybe a chance to start the itertools.cycle with the color after red!? Do you know how many colors are in the set, before the cycle starts again?

Comment: You mean the default color cycle? You can test this yourself by doing `[ax_color_cycle.next() for ii in xrange(10)]` - you'll see that it gives you `['b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'b', 'g', 'r']`, i.e. it repeats every 8 lines.

Comment: ok, thx. this is in my case unfavorable. I need more then a colorbar.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a 'colorbar', but you can create your own color cycle as long or as short as you like by varying the number of strings in the list you pass to `cycle`. As well as strings you could also give it RGBA tuples or hex values ([see here](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) for other ways to specify colors in matplotlib).

Comment: I think `_get_lines.color_cycle` is no longer there https://matplotlib.org/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_1.5.0.html?highlight=color_cycle#color-cycle-deprecated